# Getting Most recent ID & Product Revenue from Transactional Table

Tags: sql

I am getting all the combinations of ID & products & revenue when I am using max(biling date) (see code). I only want to combination of Id & Product & Revenue for the most recent billing date.

```
 select Id, product, product_category, Revenue, max(Billing_date)
    from Table1
    group by 1,2,3,4
```

Data has different combinations of Products & revenue & billing dates (it is a transactional table). But I only want to combination of **ID**+**Products**+**ProductCategory**+**Revenue** for the most recent billing date only. (not the whole transactional history history of combination of Id & prodcut for max(billing_date)).

There are different ID/Product combinations so I need to get the id/Product combinations for the latest data. Like **id001+ProdcutA+Dec12,2020**; **id001+ProdcutB+Dec 12,2020** & NOT **id001+ProdcutC+Nov12,2020**.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.  Do you want just the maximum billing date in the data?

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution using window functions:

```
select Id, product, product_category, Revenue, Billing_date
from (select t1.*, 
             rank() over (order by billing_date desc) as seqnum
      from Table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the most recent billing date per `id`/`product` combination, use `partition by`:

```
             rank() over (partition by id, product order by billing_date desc) as seqnum
```

Comment: I know this solution BUT this works for id/product combination.

Comment: There are different ID/Product combinations so I need to get the id/Product combinations for the latest data. Like **id001+ProdcutA+Dec12,2020**; **id001+ProdcutB+Dec 12,2020**  & NOT **id001+ProdcutC+Nov12,2020**

Comment: @EthanSmih . . .That is what the last expression does.